# Static files issue with docker multi services with relative static folder reference behind nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 or more containers/docker services running behind Nginx reverse proxy

/app1/   ->  localhost:4000
/app2/   ->  localhost:5000
.
.
.

Problem is static files doesn't get loaded when accessed via proxy_pass URLs, but runs correctly when accessed separately using port references.

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;
    server {

        listen 80;
        location  /app1/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5566/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /app2/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        }

        location /app3/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.
PS: Subdomain creation is one of the options but I am looking for any other alternatives if exists.

Comment: can you also include your nginx config?

Comment: I have added the conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Do each docker run independently? I think docker-compose can help you. I wonder if you have such problems.  with docker-compose, the services are intercommunicating, use nginx proxy apps

[docker-compose config](https://github.com/bbotte/bbotte.com/blob/master/docker-compose-publish/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: Yes. It runs independently but all the whole docker set up is done in a single staging VM. And docker-compose link shared by you suggests on the creation of subdomains, which I want to avoid!